# Read excel file in react native

Tags: reactjs, excel, react-native

I try to use the data of an existing excel file in a react native application. I tried with xlsx and Exceljs but each time I had mistakes. What is the best way to use Excel data (This means retrieving data from each cell in the excel table) in a reactnative application please ?

This is an example of a code that I tried to use, but it's wrong (I have the following mistake:  `Unhandled promise rejection, [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.constants.F_OK')]`
)

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile("Liste_qcm2.xlsx")
    .then(function() {
        ws = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1")
        cell = ws.getCell('A1').value
        console.log(cell)
    });
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used excels, but it appears that readFile is for NodeJS (it takes a file path, not a File object).

Here's a snippet for SheetJS (xlsx) that runs client-side:

```
    const fileData = await file.arrayBuffer()
    const workbook = XLSX.read(fileData)
    const firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0]
    const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]
```

The `file` value is a `File` object from a file Input.

**UPDATE**
The above snippet gets the File object from `<Input type="file" ...>` element. ReactNative doesn't built-in support for reading/writing files natively, but there are modules that bridge the gap, e.g. [ReactNative](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-access)

Here is the [SheetJS ReactNative demo](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/tree/master/demos/react) that shows how to get up and running.

Here's a snippet that reads each column in the 1st row of data. You can turn this into a double loop to visit every cell in the spreadsheet.

```
  function getHeaderRow(sheet: XLSX.WorkSheet) {
    const headers = []
    const range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref'] ?? '')
    const row = range.s.r
    for (let col = range.s.c; col <= range.e.c; ++col) {
      const cell = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: col, r: row })] /* find the cell in the first row */
      const header = (cell && cell.t) ? XLSX.utils.format_cell(cell) : "UNKNOWN " + col
      headers.push(header)
    }
    return headers
  }
```

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t understand how to use your snippet. Where do I enter the path of my 'test.xlsx' file? How do I display the entire first line for example?